# Linq Substring by Index

Tags: vb.net, linq, substring

I got a List containing Integer values and a String. For example

```
DetermineDigits = {1,8,16,24}
String = "|Field1, Field2; Field26"
```

I want to get following output:

```
Dim output as List(Of String) = Feld1
                                Feld2
                                Feld3
```

I tried

```
For i = 1 To DetermineDigits.Count - 1
    Dim NoOfDigits As Integer = DetermineDigits(i) - DetermineDigits(i - 1) - 1
    tmpStr = String.Substring(DetermineDigits(i - 1), NoOfDigits)
    list.add(tmpStr)
Next
```

which works, but I'd rather use Linq. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `DetermineDigits` here?

Comment: it's the list of integer determining where the next substring is going to start

Comment: I jut ran your code that you say works - and got out `{ "Field1", " Field2" }`. There's a space at the start of the second string, and there's no third string. Can you please clarify if the example output is what you need or if the "which works" code is correct?

Comment: you're right. determinedigits is missing a digit in this case. I'll edit that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `Enumerable.Range()` combined with `Select()` to iterate through `DetermineDigits` indexes:

```
Dim DetermineDigits = {1, 8, 16}
Dim Str = "|Field1, Field2; Field26"
Dim pos = DetermineDigits.Concat(New Integer() {Str.Length}).ToArray()

Dim output = Enumerable.Range(1, pos.Count() - 1) _
    .Select(Function(i) Str.Substring(pos(i - 1), pos(i) - pos(i - 1)))
```

Mind the `pos` array which is the `DetermineDigits` with last substring end position added to it. Without this addition you're rather missing the last substring.

Alternatively you may consider using `Zip()` to get a list of {StartPos, EndPos} indexes for each of your substring.

---

That being said I suggest considering to use regex to extract your substrings. Those in your example can be easily grabbed with simple `\w+` so you'll end up with quite compact code:

```
Dim Str = "|Field1, Field2; Field26"
Dim output = Regex.Matches(Str, "\w+").Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value).ToList()
```

NB: don't forget to add `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`.

If your substring pattern is more complex, we may further elaborate the regex.